# Drawing bitmaps with alpha channel: please advise... (some solutions and speed issues)

Tags: android, performance, bitmap, rgb, alpha

I have a rather big number of small bitmaps (100+, size about 40x40) each one have some opaque and some transparent parts and i need to paint them respecting these areas.

Bitmaps are in ARGB format, 888(rgb) plus a 256bit alpha channel, standard like in PNG format.

The only (working) way i found to draw them is the following approach:

1. create a bitmap (ARGB_8888)
2. fill the bitmap with the raw data
3. extract the alpha layer from the bitmap
4. create a BitmapShader (RGB_565) based on the original bitmap
5. Create a paint for the bitmap which uses the created shader
6. Then paint the alpha mask using the paint with the special BitmapShader.

The initialization code is run only once, of course:

```
void initializeTile( int t ){
// Allocate the bitmap:
Bitmap original_data = Bitmap.createBitmap( tile_w, tile_h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
// Fill with raw data (this is actually native C++ code):
populateBitmap( original_data );
// Get the alpha mask:
tile_mask[ t ] = original_data.extractAlpha();
// Create the bitmap shader:
tile_data = original_data.copy( Bitmap.Config.RGB_565, false);
// Create the shader:
BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(tile_data, CLAMP, CLAMP);

// Create the paint:
tile_paint[ t ] = new Paint();
tile_paint[ t ].setDither(true);
tile_paint[ t ].setAntiAlias(true);
tile_paint[ t ].setFilterBitmap(true);
tile_paint[ t ].setShader( shader );
}
```

And the paint code is the most simple possible, and it's in the main draw loop:

```
void paintTile(t){
canvas.drawBitmap( tile_mask[ t ],  tile_x[ t], tile_y[ t], tile_paint[ t] );
}
```

Now, on phones like the Ideos (Android 2.2) it run smooth and fine, but on other phones like the top-end Samsung Galaxy SII (Android 2.3) it's crappy and slow. This does not make much sense to me...

So, what do you think of this approach? Are there better, faster, ways to achieve the same result?

And, why do you think it's so slow on modern, fast hardware? Is there any ways to improve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, after some work i found out a better solution. I cannot answer my own questions, so please do if you know more than me.

But, in case more people needs this, i am posting my new solution, which is much faster albeit a bit more complicated. The key idea is to use the shader approach ONLY during initialization and not for painting.

To do this, i create a new bitmap which will contain the "clipped" bitmap (with all the transparent areas cleared) using the shader approach, then paint that clipped bitmap without any shader in the draw code.

```
void initializeTile( int t ){
// Allocate the bitmap:
Bitmap original_data = Bitmap.createBitmap( tile_w, tile_h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
// Fill with raw data (this is actually native C++ code):
populateBitmap( original_data );

// Now make a new bitmap to be clipped:
Bitmap clipped_data = Bitmap.createBitmap( tile_w, tile_h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(clipped_data);
Paint clip_paint = new Paint();
clip_paint.setDither(true);
clip_paint.setAntiAlias(true);
clip_paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
clip_paint.setShader( new BitmapShader(original_data, CLAMP, CLAMP));
// Paint the clipped bitmap:
canvas.drawBitmap( tile_mask[ t ], 0, 0, clip_paint );
//Use the clipped bitmap as original bitmap:
tile_data[ t ] = clipped_data;
}
```

And also drawing code:

```
void paintTile(t){
canvas.drawBitmap( tile_data[ t ],  tile_x[ t], tile_y[ t], null );
}
```

Overall, this is much faster.
Still it's unclear to me WHY Android would not paint my alpha-channelled bitmaps properly without all this mess!